# iOS8 freezing in [GAIDataStore save]

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, google-analytics, ios8

I have been tracking down a bug in my project which is causing the app to freeze, forcing the user to restart.

It is only possible in the release build, so it has been tricky to track down. It is a social app where users upload photos to their profile. The problem occurred only on first run after initial download or after reseting privacy settings, then going trough the flow to post a photo. During the post the user is asked for permission to access the photos, and also to access their location.

After selecting "allow" on the location services request the app became unresponsive.

So my initial investigation was around the use of the CLLocationManager, I suspected an issue with the delegate callbacks.

I was not able to reproduce with a debug configuration, but could run a release config on device and when the app became unresponsive pausing the debugger the callstack points to the Google Analytics library.

```
0   0x37a9fb38 in __psynch_cvwait ()<br>
1   0x37b1c3f8 in _pthread_cond_wait ()<br>
2   0x37b1d2dc in pthread_cond_wait ()<br>
3   0x2aa3b482 in -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] ()<br>
4   0x29c5799e in _CFXNotificationPost ()<br>
5   0x2a9879b8 in -NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo: ()<br>
6   0x29a87b96 in -NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _didSaveChanges ()<br>
7   0x29a6e12e in -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] ()<br>
8   0x002d2e82 in __21-[GAIDataStore save:]_block_invoke ()<br>
9   0x002d16b8 in -GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError: ()<br>
10  0x002d2dc2 in -[GAIDataStore save:] ()<br>
11  0x002db62a in -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] ()<br>
12  0x002dc7aa in -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueDispatch:] ()<br>
13  0x002dc5b0 in -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueModel:] ()<br>
14  0x2aa5259e in __NSThreadPerformPerform ()<br>
15  0x29d0958e in _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_ ()<br>
16  0x29d0899e in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()<br>
17  0x29d07004 in __CFRunLoopRun ()<br>
18  0x29c55620 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()<br>
19  0x29c55432 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()<br>
20  0x2a98d42c in -NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate: ()<br>
21  0x2a9db8ec in -NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run ()<br>
22  0x002cf270 in +[GAI threadMain:] ()<br>
23  0x2aa5238a in _NSThreadmain_ ()<br>
24  0x37b1ce92 in _pthread_body ()<br>
25  0x37b1ce06 in _pthread_start ()<br>
```

The issue only appears in iOS8 and I am running Google Analytics iOS SDK version 3.07.

The app is live and GAI has been integrated for several months prior to the bug showing up which was when iOS8 went live. Several posts about problems with GAI integration report problems linking libraries, but I don't believe this to be the case since it is working fine the majority of the time.

If anybody has seen any simmular issues or has any suggestions this would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: I have now also created the issue on the debug configuration as there was some logic in my app to stop the analytics tracking in debug. The app is freezing after calling 'startUpdatingLocation'. I believe iOS8 has introduced some changes to location services. So I now suspect this is why it is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You are listening to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, the GAI SDK will post this notification, and GAI SDK is using **a different persistent store coordinator** from yours, so if GAI SDK post this notification and you try to merge the notification, you are merging changes of two different persistent store, this may cause problem.

The solution is simple, when listening to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, you only respond to notification comes from your background context.
by using the `object` parameter in

```
[NSNotificationCenter -addObserver:selector:name:object:]
```

you can only listening to the background context, then the GAI context won't trigger a context merge.

Comment: FYI, I'm seeing a very similar freeze in an iOS 9 app, and our code does not do anything with NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification.  The backtrace is slightly different (the new GAI SDK apparently uses NSCondition in its save method, and nothing ever signals that condition), but I suspect it is the same bug, and I suspect it is a real bug in GAI.

Comment: Correction: That NSCondition wait is part of Apple's performSelector:onThread:... method.  I suspect this is a deadlock, where code on the main thread is scheduling work on another thread, which has to perform some task on the main thread before it can finish.  I'm not certain, however, because I foolishly only took a backtrace of the running thread.  :-(